# System.getProperty from CQ5.6.1

Tags: aem, sling

I am using a 3rd party jar file in my CQ5.6.1 project. A program in the jar uses `System.getProperty()` to read some property file location.

I am not able to find a way to set these properties for the program to read. Any idea how I can do this in CQ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use java options or command line arguments to pass system properties

**Java Options**

In Windows

```
set _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Dargument1=value1 -Dargument2=value2
```

In *nix

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Dargument1=value1 -Dargument2=value2"
```

**Command Line**

```
java -jar jarfile.jar -Dargument1=value1 -Dargument2=value2
```

Then you can get the property value by using `System.getProperty()`

```
System.getProperty("argument1")//Will print value1 
System.getProperty("argument2")//Will print value2
```